# Install AMD Vega 7 Mobile (448 Shader / 1600MHz) driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I have bought the HP ProBook 455 G7 1B7W4ES and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Audio, wlan and graphics work out of the box. The only problem is, if I connect my HDMI cable with laptop and monitor, nothing happens.

It seems that my integrated graphicprocessor is called `AMD Vega 7 Mobile (448 Shader / 1600MHz)`.

I was searching at [amd](https://www.amd.com/en/support) for drivers and the closes that I found was the "AMD Radeon VII 2nd generation Vega.

[image]

I installed the driver according to the docs with `./amdgpu-install -y`.

[image]

After reboot I it seems nothing changed. Still the old driver `lshw -c video`:

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0600000-e067ffff
```

---

I had to disable secure boot, now at least HDMI works (but only when `amdgpu` is installed).

Although the output from `sudo lshw -c video` is unchanged:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0600000-e067ffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newer kernel for AMD Renoir.

Try the 5.8 (or latest) [mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

***How do I install an upstream kernel?***

*"The build directories are nicely organized into per architecture groups. For example, if one is using a 64-bit/amd64 architecture and wants the generic kernel version you would want those files marked A, from the appropriate group. "*

E.g.

Download **four** 5.8 generic files: incl 2 headers and modules into dir.
CD into dir and:

```
 sudo dpkg -i *.deb
 reboot
```

See [mutatis mutandis](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Choose_the_proper_upstream_kernel_files)

Comment: I have just disabeld secure boot, now at least the HDMI is working, but `sudo lshw -c video` output is unchanged.

Comment: I don't think you need amdgou, I would uninstall that first and try the generic 5.8 kernel.

Comment: I updated the kernel first and then uninstalled the driver (is the order important?). After restart, HDMI was not working. I reinstalled the amdgpu driver, now HDMI is working again. I was not able to install the `generic` kernel because it requires just the kernel (?) so I installed `linux-headers-5.8.0-050800_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_all.deb`

Comment: What does `uname -a`  output?

Comment: `Linux adam-HP-ProBook-455-G7 5.4.0.-42-generic #46-Ubuntu .....` Looks like the Kerne 5.8 was not installed? I downloaded the file and run `sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-5.8.0-050800_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_all.deb` and the output looked succesfull. Shall I rerun it?

Comment: Read carefully the instructions: For example, if one is using a 64-bit/amd64 architecture and wants the generic kernel version you would want those files marked A, from the appropriate group. " that means 4 files.